# On click map function is opening all the Pop-up in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image: Here is how popup appears]I've rendered a popup for every product ,so when some one clicks the icon a popup is going to come.
The problem now i'm facing is that on clicking any product all the popup is getting open.since it is inside map function .
My requirement here is to only open the popup related to product and close all the other popup.

```
export default class index extends Component {
 state = {
    isPopoverOpen: false,
  };

  openPopup = () => {
    this.setState({ isPopoverOpen: !this.state.isPopoverOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
       this.props.dataArray.map((x, index) => {
        <button  onClick={() => this.openPopup()}> Open </button>
                        {x.id != index ?
                        <PopUp
                         isPopoverOpen={this.state.isPopoverOpen}
                        /> : '' }
            }

    )
  }


}



//Code for Popup Component


 export class index extends Component {
    state = {
        isPopoverOpen: false,
    };



    // add business user
    onClickOutside = async () => {
        this.setState({ isPopoverOpen: false })

    };  

    ClickedPop = () => {

        this.setState({ isPopoverOpen: !isPopoverOpen })
    }

    render() {
        const { isPopoverOpen } = this.state;
        return (
           <PopUpWrapper>
               <Popover
                isOpen={this.props.isPopoverOpen}
                position={['right']}
                padding={0}
                onClickOutside={() => console.log("<<<<  Clicked Outside! >>>>>")}
                content={({ position, targetRect, popoverRect }) => (

                        <PopUpWrapper>
                        <div
                            style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', opacity: 0.7 }}
                            //onClick={() => this.setState({ isPopoverOpen: !isPopoverOpen })}
                        >
                            Hi! I'm popover content. Here's my position: {position}.
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add the bucket" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" />
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">+</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </PopUpWrapper>

                )}
            >
                <div>

                </div>
            </Popover>
           </PopUpWrapper>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: They all share the same state, so when `isPopoverOpen` is true, they're all going to open. Each popover needs some unique value which you can generate and store in the state.

Comment: Could you please add your  `PopUp` component source code

Comment: @SterlingArcher The Id is unique for every popup.But how could i compare ?With which value do i need to compare so that it will avoid duplicate popup ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not react expert, but it may b due to, you are taking state as globally in this class.

creating your state inside onclick handler may solve your problem.

Comment: You may want to go more in depth on this, as it theoretically solves the issue (maybe) but in practice, it won't help future readers. Code examples should be included for a good answer